# Expensive travel insurance due to my medical history

Tags: health, insurance

3 years ago I had a malignant melanoma removed and have had no recurrence since.  However when I try to obtain travel insurance I am either refused point blank or I have to pay way over the odds.
It seems to me highly unlikely that any recurrence would have a serious detrimental effect on my health over the period of 2 weeks, the length of time I would be insured, but I can't find a solution.
Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Probably depends a lot on the country you live in, and the regulations that apply there?

Comment: As I have never had any inquiry into my current health before getting a travel insurance, I am sure it has to do with your location. Not sure how widespread it is though.

Comment: This is kind of open ended. Are you asking for advice on how to find a better insurance policy? Or a new company altogether? What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3):

I've used https://www.worldnomads.com/ before and i'm pretty sure they didn't request a medical history to provide cover. They cover residents of any country.

They might not be cheapest option (seems to be $100 per month), but i doubt you'll pay more than other travellers with them.

They have competitors in this international travel insurance, so do compare.